# Components dont update after state changes

Tags: reactjs, redux

```
case 'ADD_POLL':
    deepFreeze(state);
    state = [
        ...state,
        {
            votingPolls: [
                ...state[state.length-1].votingPolls, 
                {
                    name : action.payload
                }
            ]
        }
    ];

    return [state[state.length-1]];
```

this is one of the cases in my reducer and for some reason the component is not updating even though the state changes without any mutations.

Comment: What does your mapStateToProps method look like?

Comment: this reducer is so confusing. your state will always have 1 element? is this intentional?